# Child component style overflows parent

Tags: css, angular

I recently started learning frontend development with Angular, and am trying to create a view ('Witness Reports') which will include a grid of filter cards that the user can click to filter out stories, based on theme. I have created a **witness-reports** component that acts as the page/view, and a **report-filters** component for the cards. I'm currently testing out the view, like so

**witness-reports.component.html**

```
<div>
<h1>User Reports</h1>
<div class="filterGrid">
    <app-report-filters></app-report-filters>
    <app-report-filters></app-report-filters>
    <app-report-filters></app-report-filters>    
    <app-report-filters></app-report-filters>
    <app-report-filters></app-report-filters>
    <app-report-filters></app-report-filters>            
</div>
```

**witness-reports.component.html**

```
.filterGrid {
background-color: blue;
display: grid;
column-gap: 50px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 400px);
}
```

And the filter template

**report-filters.component.html**

```
<a class="filterItem">Report Filter</a>
```

**report-filters.component.css**

```
.filterItem {
background-color: purple;
text-align: center; 
margin: 20px;
padding:  100px;
}
```

When I was testing it out by keeping the filterItem class in the parent stylesheet and using it as an attribute on the children `<app-report-filters class="filterItem">`, the children got arranged correctly and the parent expanded to accomodate. As soon as I moved the styling to the child component to keep it modular (I plan to reuse similar filters), playing with the childrens' margin causes them to overflow and render *over* the parent (the blue block is the parent `<div>` element):

[image]

I've searched around and stumbled upon the concept of collapsing margins, but this doesn't seem to be the case here. I'm also aware of using the overflow attribute, but this isn't my intended goal. Is there a way to make the parent expand? The filters are going to be added dynamically from a list of categories.

Comment: You can open your browser's developer console (F12 by default) and inspect the elements to see what CSS is being applied. Are you sure the CSS taking effect is the same in both cases? Also helps if you can provide a runnable example.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped immensely. I foolishly thought that the whole host got styled, when it only applies to the inner template. Going back to the docs, I discovered the ':host' selector and this fixed the problem.